# Possible to specify just one of the parameters when creating object using Autofixture? (C# XUnit & Autofixture)

Tags: c#, xunit, autofixture

I have a complex object from a library I need a mock of that takes multiple parameters in the constructor, one of them is an enum, unfortunately

```
_fixture.Create<MyObject>()
```

is failing because the default enum it chooses as a parameter isn't allowed

is there a way to specify which enum to use in the constructor when generating objects?

Answer (score 0):

You can use .Build instead of .Create.

So something like:

```
fixture.Build<MyObject>().With(t=>t.MyEnum, Enum.SomeValue).Create()
```